# Why pandas xs doesn't drop levels even if drop_level = True

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,10000), -1),
                   'b':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,10000), -1),
                   'c':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,10000), -1),
                   'value':np.random.randint(0,100,10001)})

dfi = df.set_index(['a','b','c'])
dfi.sortlevel(inplace = True)

dfi.xs((2,1,7), drop_level=True)
             value    time
a    b    c        
2    1    7     33    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000033
          7     70    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000070
          7     75    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000075
          7     53    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000053
          7     28    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000028
          7     21    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000021
          7     36    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000036
          7     43    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000043
          7     67    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000067
9 rows × 2 columns
```

It doesn't drop for `dfi.xs((-1,-1,-1), drop_level=True)` (one 1 match)

However it drops if `dfi.xs((2,1), drop_level=True)` ?

pandas version '0.13.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is filed here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6507

Let me know if there is any progress or this is indeed a defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

what you are asking for doesn't make sense, becuase by definition you have multiple matches.

you could do this if you want:

```
In [43]: dfi.xs((2,1,7)).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[43]: 
    value
0      49
1      98
2       2
3      80
4      47
5      74
6      37
7      23
8       0
9       7
10     58
11     82
12     44

[13 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: then why `dfi.xs((2,1), drop_level=True)` can drop?

Comment: And not drop for `dfi.xs((-1,-1,-1), drop_level=True)` (one 1 match)

Comment: its prob a bug (see your other question)