# When does Pandas xs drop dimensions and how can I force it to/not to?

Tags: python, pandas

Sometimes I see `xs` would return a Series from a DataFrame if the return is only one row, sometimes not. How to enforce it happen / not happen? (may be related to [Why pandas xs doesn't drop levels even if drop_level = True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066771/why-pandas-xs-doesnt-drop-levels-even-if-drop-level-true))

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,10000), -1),
                   'b':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,10000), -1),
                   'c':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,10000), -1),
                   'value':np.random.randint(0,100,10001)})

df.set_index(['a','b','c'], inplace=True)
df.sortlevel(inplace = True)

df.xs((-1,-1,-1), drop_level=True)

            value
a   b   c   
-1  -1  -1   43
```

Here it returns a one row data frame instead of a series.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a1','a2','a3'],
                   'b':['b1','b1','b1'],
                   'c':[1,1,1],
                   'value':np.random.randint(0,100,3)})
df2.set_index(['a','b','c'], inplace=True)
df2.sortlevel(inplace = True)
df2.xs(('a1','b1',1))

value    30
Name: (a1, b1, 1), dtype: int64
```

In this case only  Series is returned.

### Update

My colleague just discovered that if the length of df is big, it will return a data frame, otherwise, it will return a series.

```
n=25
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,n), -1),
                   'b':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,n), -1),
                   'c':np.append(np.random.randint(0,10,n), -1),
                   'value':np.random.randint(0,100,n+1)})

df.set_index(['a','b','c'], inplace=True)
df.sortlevel(inplace = True)

display(df.xs((-1,-1,-1), drop_level=True))
df.index.get_loc((-1,-1,-1))
```

The boundary of `n` is not even consistent, it might due to the number of distinctive values in the indices.

However, the result whether it is a Series or Data Frame depends on the if `get_loc` returns 0 or `Slice(0,1,None)`

What more, if the key is not in the indices, `get_loc` would sometimes throw `KeyError` exception, sometimes returns `Slice(0,0,None)`.

Bug report is filed. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6501

Comment: might be a bug, pls file a report on github

Comment: I filed, and it got closed. Seems no point raising an issue on github.

Comment: the issue you filed was completely different than the issue of drop level not working with a fully specified indexer -that might be a bug - what you filed is not

Comment: I closed your issue because you still have not explained what you are actually doing -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, they are all defined behaviors. So it is my responsibility to deal with it.